# partial view does not work in production environment but in local

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, partial-views, partial

I am doing a profile module and everything seems to work very well locally, but when I published my files on my server, now it is not loading the partial views, I already tried restarting the service, putting files as embedded records and changing my methods of calls via ajax and nothing works, any ideas?

Event Call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: accion.ObtenerTipoPerfil,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: async,
            data: { tipoUsuarioId: val },
            success: function (result) {
                ctrl.divTipoUsuario.html(result);
                ctr.botonRegresar.show();
                ctr.botonGuardar.show().disabledElement(true);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                ctrl.dvWidgetFooter.WidgetTotales(tipoMensaje.warning, window.Mensaje_Error_Servicio);
            }
```

My Method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ObtenerAreaPerfil(int? areaId)
    {

        var service = new ServicioSecurityManagementContractClient();
        var listaCompara = service.ObtainMethod(new ObtenerAreaComparadaReq { UsuarioGuid = Sesion.Usuario.GUID, AreaId = Parse.ObjectToInt(areaId) });
        var listaAsigna = service.ObtainMethod2(new ObtenerPerfilAsignadoReq { AreaId = Parse.ObjectToInt(areaId) });
        List<AreaPerfilModel> listaPerfilcompara = new List<AreaPerfilModel>();
        List<AreaPerfilModel> listaPerfilasigna = new List<AreaPerfilModel>();

        foreach (var l in listaCompara.Perfiles)
        {
            listaPerfilcompara.Add(new AreaPerfilModel { IdPerfil = l.PerfilId, NombrePerfil = l.PerfilNombre });
        }
        foreach (var l in listaAsigna.Perfiles)
        {
            listaPerfilasigna.Add(new AreaPerfilModel { IdPerfil = l.PerfilId, Descripcion = l.PerfilNombre });
        }
        ViewBag.Asignados = listaPerfilasigna.ToList();

        var listaPerfil = listaPerfilcompara.ToList().Take(500);

        return PartialView("ObtenerAreaPerfil",listaPerfil);

    }
```

Comment: Could be a path problem. Are you using `@Url.Action()` to set your `accion.ObtenerTipoPerfil` variable?

Comment: no, I'm using an array in js, this: accion:{
obtenerPerfil: '/Controller/Method''
}

Comment: Do this instead: `accion:{ obtenerPerfil: '@Url.Action("ObtenerAreaPerfil")' }` If the action is in a different controller than the View calling it, pass the controller name as a second argument to `@Url.Action()`.

Comment: I already did what you suggested, it still does not work.

Comment: Then you'll need to do some troubleshooting. "nothing works" isn't very helpful for us. Does the AJAX request result in an error? What's that error? Does the ObtenerAreaPerfil action get invoked? Things like that that you can determine by using the debugger.

Comment: Write out the actual url you are posting the request to into the javascript console and check.

Comment: have asked this question, thank's all!